# Is it a good practice to store SQL query in the database?

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python

My Usecase:

We allow the users of the system to create a list(i.e segment) of contact details based on the variety of the filters from the UI. So they create the segment using a form to select say all people living in a particular state.

So the issue here is that, when the new contacts are added, I want these segments to be updated as well. The solution that I can think of is saving SQL query for each segment and update each segment when new contacts are added using these SQL queries.

I thought of saving only parameters in a json string format but complication in that case is filters available are over multiple tables and there is no way to generate the dynamic SQL query as it involves joins and different filters (i.e. 'in', 'endswith', etc).

I don't think either of them is the best solution. Any better ideas?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Update: JSON parameter and Query I need

```
{'is_buyer': ['1'], 'is_executive_member': ['1'], 'is_member': ['1'], 'survey_participant': ['1'], 'cluster': ['A'], 'state': ['state1'], 'city': ['ab', 'cd'], 'gender': ['male']}
```

Expected query output:

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` INNER JOIN `contacts_clusters` ON (`contacts`.`KEY` = `contacts_clusters`.`KEY`) WHERE (`contacts`.`IS_BUYER` IN (1) AND `contacts`.`IS_EXECUTIVE_MEMBER` IN (1) AND `contacts`.`IS_MEMBER` IN (1) AND `contacts`.`SURVEY_ID` IS NOT NULL AND `contacts_clusters`.`CLUSTER` IN ('A') AND `contacts`.`STATE` IN ('state1') AND `contacts`.`CITY` IN ('ab', 'cd') AND `contacts`.`GENDER` IN ('male'))
```

This is just one of the example of segment filter. There are much more parameters and tables which can used for the creation of segment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off storing the required parameters for the segment, then when new contacts are added, you'd check if the new contacts match according to the stored segment parameters. If they do, then you'd update the segment.

Comment: Yeah, but as I said in that case, I am not able to generate the query using those parameters itself because it involves multiple tables and different kind of filters. The generation of SQL query dynamically becomes an issue here for me.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more details about the query generation? It shouldn't be impossible to serialize the parameters.

Comment: I have added the json parameters and output query example. Please have a look.

Comment: Are you currently generating a queryset for this? If so, please include that code.

Comment: Nope, I have not written any logic for generating the queryset yet, as it was resulting in lots of if else statements (do this for a particular parameter, do that for other parameter). That's why I was thinking of storing the SQL itself.

Comment: If there's an end to the if statements, then you can very likely write do this with Django's ORM and storing the parameters as JSON. Storing SQL isn't a great idea given the problems you're going to encounter when the schema changes.